# Vim function to call bash script with argument and return result

Tags: bash, vim, plugins

I have a bash script which takes a single argument and returns around 8-10 lines of text.

I'd like to be able to call this script from within vim.  Ideally by highlighting a string of characters as the argument.  I'd then like the output of the script to be displayed in a new pane.

I'm new to vim so I'm not sure if this can be done simply by creating a command in my vimrc file or if I need to create a plugin.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

after a bit of googling I've come up with

```
function! Foo(a1)
    new
    r !myscript a:a1
endfunction
```

This doesn't quite work yet.  It seems to pass the name a:a1 rather than the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start with a simple function like so (**note:** the sample uses `echo` as the script... Kinda lame... but you get the idea)

```
function! CallMyScript(params)
    new                 " open a new buffer
    " se buftype=nofile " add spice to taste, e.g.
    silent! exec "r!echo '" . a:params . "'"
endfunction
```

and then a mapping for visual mode like;

```
:vnoremap QQ y:call CallMyScript(@")<Enter>
```

This will call the script with the currently selected text when you hit <kbd>Q</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: I'm a wee bit confused about the ". a:params ."  say I had two arguemnts to pass to my script how would I change that?

Comment: I'm assuming shell quoting applies; Dropping the sinqle quotest would probably do what you what

Comment: What if the script is a bash function or alias? It (didn't work) wasn't available for me in this way (possibly due to no bashrc being loaded), so I had to retype everything in a one-liner. Isn't there a smarter way?

Comment: @dezza in that case, call the right program (e.g. bash): `bash -c my_alias`. ***Be aware*** of shell quoting/escaping. Not for the faint of heart :) (Just make a shell script for it?)

Comment: sehe: It actually returned "command not found" .. Are you sure the chain of sources (.bashrc and from there) are happening with "bash -c" ?

Comment: @dezza You tell me :/ I think it depends on how you setup your system (and whether you are getting a restricted or a interactive shell). Try `bash -ic myalias`. Or, `man bash`