# VIM: Execute script and display result for complex file type

Tags: c++, bash, vim

I have a  custom very complex file format. This format can be parsed into human readable by a bash script (which ends up calling a c++ program to actualy parse it).

What can I do so that when vim trys to read this file, instead of simply opening it should it first should call this script and then display its result instead of the contents of the file

Comment: I think this addresses just that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974440/vim-function-to-call-bash-script-with-argument-and-return-result/6974925#6974925

Comment: A rather boring solution is to create a shell-script that does the parsing and then open vim on the generated data.

Comment: that link doesnt answer the questions since my script doesn't accept text it acc epts a file path and secondly I want solution where when vim opens a file of a specfic type it automaticallly calls this scripts and displays the results instead of the original binaryish text

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufRead *.yourext call ParseMyComplexFile()     " When reading your complex files

function ParseMyComplexFile()
    let l:fname = expand('%:t')                     " Copy current file name to l:fname
    enew                                            " Open new empty buffer in place of current one
    setlocal buftype=nofile                         " (scratch buffer) New buffer is not related to a file and will not be written
    setlocal bufhidden=hide                         " (scratch buffer) Don't unload the buffer when it is hidden
    setlocal noswapfile                             " (scratch buffer) No swap file for this buffer
    " Execute your script on the file and change the name of the buffer to 'parsed <filename>'
    silent execute "read !yourscript.sh " . l:fname         
    silent execute "file parsed " . l:fname         
    1d                                              " Delete the first unwanted empty row
    1                                               " Position to first row
endfunction
```

replacing `yourext` and `yourscript.sh` with proper values.

You will have two new buffers: one with the original file and one with the parsed output (this will be the current buffer).